# Device Geolocation doesn't work using multiple subdomains

Tags: location

I am using the module [Smart IP](http://drupal.org/project/smart_ip) and in particular its sub module Device Geolocation to detect the users position. The latter uses the method

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error)
```

to get the position form the browser. Everything worked fine till I started to use subdomains as language detection method, like:

```
de.example.com
en.example.com etc.
```

Now the detection always fails, will say, calls the error handler function. In Chromiums console I get the message:

```
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

In spite of the fact I gave the browser the permission to detect my position for each and every subdomain.

How to get the method `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to work with various sub domains?